# Access 2016: How to save Form entry data in a specific table based on the entry data?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I spent about ten minutes trying to find the best question that describes my problem, so it may not be the best one.

I am doing a database from scratch for practice. This is a brief explanation of what I have:

I have tables  A,  B,  C, and D.------         A,B,C,D are part numbers.

Then I have a Form where I have to enter the part number, date, temperature, name, result1, and result2.

Here is what I am trying to do:
- If I enter part number A, I want to save all the information in the table A.
- If I enter part number B, I want to save all the information in the Table B.
- Same with the rest of the part numbers.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Thanks you all for your comments.

Comment: I guess the real questions is why are there multiple parts tables?

Comment: Now that I think, I guess I can have only one table, and I always can filter or export it to excel to see it by part number.                                                                                  What I am really looking for is for a pass or fail when I enter the results, so every part number have different limits.

Comment: well then you need to ask SQL related questions, as this type of data filtering is what sql is good at

Answer (score 0):

This is actually really simple to do, however the end result is pretty far from "normalized" and so I'd highly suggest you put all data in one table and have a "PartNum" field or something so it can be filtered when necessary.

However, to answer your question...  The way you can do this is with an [unbound form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355152.aspx).  If you do not associate a specific table as the form's source data, it is considered unbound.  Comparatively, if you bind a form to a specific table and then bind the fields to controls, as soon as you enter the data in the form it is immediately written to the table.  Using an unbound form allows you to have full control over what data is written and to which table it's written to.

So, using an unbound form, you can simply put a "Save" button on the form and put VBA in the OnClick event of this button.  In the OnClick event of the button you could check the PartNum field and, based on the value, write to the appropriate table.

For instance:

```
Public Sub btnSave_OnClick()
dim db as Database
dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
'Find out which table to write to
if Me.PartNum.Text = "A" then
  MyTable = "PartNumA"
elseif Me.PartNum.Text = "B" then
  MyTable = "PartNumB"
else (etc...)
end if

Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from " & MyTable & "")
rec.AddNew
rec("PartNum") = Me.PartNum.Text
rec("Date") = Me.Date.Text
rec("Temperature") = Me.Temperature.Text
etc...
rec.Update

rec.Close
db.Close
End Sub
```

The above is entirely "aircode"; completely untested and hypothetical but probably pretty close to what you'd actually write.

Comment: Jhonny-  Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. That makes sense to me as to answer my question.  However, I plan to use this database to record 20 tests/day.  Which of the two options would you recommend, so database don't get slow over the time?

Comment: I've used Access tables with up to 500,000 records without any issues, as long as the table is properly indexed.  I'd definitely recommend using a normalized table, it just makes life easier.  Then you don't have to write any extra code to know which table you're working with.  However, I'd also still recommend using an unbound form, it's much easier to cancel a record before it's written than it is when you use a bound form.